# How to scroll Looped Data?

Tags: objective-c

What I need to achieve is the ability to swipe up and down to scroll between the records presented, as after about 10 records it now becomes offscreen.

```
-(void)createInfo:(NSString *)dateField withField:(NSString *)setName withFieldKvMax:(NSString *)kvField withFieldMaMax:(NSString *)maField withFieldId:(int)idField withFieldIncrement98:(int)increment98 withFieldIncrement147:(int)increment147 withFieldIncrement118:(int)increment118
{

    UILabel *dateTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, increment98, 208, 21)];
    dateTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", setName];
    dateTimeLabel.tag = idField;
    [_scrollView addSubview:dateTimeLabel];

    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, increment118, 331, 21)];
    infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Max mA: %@ Max kV: %@ %@", maField, kvField, dateField];
    [infoLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    infoLabel.tag = idField;
    [_scrollView addSubview:infoLabel];

    UIProgressView *progBar = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, increment147, 343, 2)];
    progBar.tag = idField;
    [_scrollView addSubview:progBar];

    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(deleteInfo:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [deleteButton setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(329, increment98, 30, 30);
    deleteButton.tag = idField;
    [_scrollView addSubview:deleteButton];
}
```

So the database adds to the scrollview each iterate for row. But I cannot scroll with the scrollview even after the rows exceed the height of the scrollview.

The scrollview is delegated to the viewcontroller

Not sure where to look as most answers just involve ( data greater than height should scroll )

Comment: I've now added all the `self.view` to `self.uiscrollview` the content is larger than the scrollview, but doesn't scroll..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, newHeight);
```

newHeight would be the last yPosistion of the object you added plus it's height.

Answer (score 0):

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(373, 4000);
```

Appears to work for now.